# Why are NULL values being coerced to a negative integer when using DBI in R

Tags: r, sqlite, r-dbi

I am connecting to a SQLite database using DBI in R using the following script

```
db = "/Path/To/Database/Foo.db"
obsTable = "obs"
obsQryStr <- paste('select * from ', obsTable)

con <-  dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = db)
importedData <- dbGetQuery( con, obsQryStr)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

The table in question has a number of columns of integer values. Here's the output of `head(importedData,12)`:

```
               time subject encounter location temp          hr sbp         dbp rr        spo2 o2Log avpu gcs concern
1  2010-01-01 08:00       2         1        1   NA          97 113          66 12         100     1    A  15       0
2  2010-01-01 08:15       2         1        1 36.2          95 110          62 12         100     1    A  15       0
3  2010-01-01 08:30       2         1        1 36.2          84  90          61 12         100     1    A  15       0
4  2010-01-01 08:45       2         1        1 36.2          80  96          55 12         100     1    A  15       0
5  2010-01-01 09:00       2         1        1 36.2          77  88          51 12         100     0    A  15       0
6  2010-01-01 09:15       2         1        1 36.3          75  91          50 12         100     0    A  15       0
7  2010-01-01 09:30       2         1        1 36.3          76  92          52 12         100     1    A  15       0
8  2010-01-01 10:00       2         1        1 36.4          73  91          52 12         100     0    A  15       0
9  2010-01-01 10:30       2         1        1 36.5          71  91          51 12         100     1    A  15       0
10 2010-01-01 11:30       2         1        1 36.6          69  92          53 12         100     1    A  15       0
11 2010-01-01 12:30       2         1        1 36.6          76 118          63 14         100     1    A  15       0
12 2010-01-01 13:00       2         1        1   NA -2147483648  NA -2147483648 NA -2147483648     1    A  15       0
```

As you can see in row 12, for some of the columns the NULL values have been replaced with -2147483648 instead of NA. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

The SQL for the corresponding rows is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sim` (
    `time`  TEXT,
    `subject`   INTEGER,
    `encounter` INTEGER,
    `location`  INTEGER,
    `temp`  REAL,
    `hr`    INTEGER,
    `sbp`   INTEGER,
    `dbp`   INTEGER,
    `rr`    INTEGER,
    `spo2`  INTEGER,
    `o2Log` INTEGER,
    `avpu`  TEXT,
    `gcs`   INTEGER,
    `concern`   INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 08:00',2,1,1,NULL,97,113,66,12,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 08:15',2,1,1,36.2,95,110,62,12,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 08:30',2,1,1,36.2,84,90,61,12,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 08:45',2,1,1,36.2,80,96,55,12,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 09:00',2,1,1,36.2,77,88,51,12,100,0,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 09:15',2,1,1,36.3,75,91,50,12,100,0,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 09:30',2,1,1,36.3,76,92,52,12,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 10:00',2,1,1,36.4,73,91,52,12,100,0,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 10:30',2,1,1,36.5,71,91,51,12,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 11:30',2,1,1,36.6,69,92,53,12,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 12:30',2,1,1,36.6,76,118,63,14,100,1,'A',15,0);
INSERT INTO `sim` (time,subject,encounter,location,temp,hr,sbp,dbp,rr,spo2,o2Log,avpu,gcs,concern) VALUES ('2010-01-01 13:00',2,1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'A',15,0);
```

The one clue I have is that the affected columns are, for some reason being converted from INT as the preferred type in the SQLite database to numeric. `sapply(importedData, class)` produces the following output:

```
    time     subject   encounter    location        temp          hr         sbp         dbp          rr        spo2 
"character"   "integer"   "integer"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "integer"   "numeric"   "integer"   "numeric" 
      o2Log        avpu         gcs     concern 
  "integer" "character"   "integer"   "integer"
```

Comment: `-2147483648` does not equal `2^-31`.  Given that `NULL` does seem to be getting rendered as `NA` in other rows/columns, I suspect that your data has some problem.

Comment: Please post the same data as stored in SQLite (not the imported result in R).

Comment: Thanks both. Have edited. Your suggestion seems most likely, Tim, but I can't see how it's happening

Comment: I have wrapped your code in a reprex but the error does not occur here: https://gist.github.com/krlmlr/1c23936abc6d55734e3d186ae5849254. What OS are you using (please also mention bitness)?

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, @krlmlr. This was on Mac OS X 10.14. Subsequent to posting this I discovered that I could not reproduce the problem on my other computer running MacOS. The R files and database are synced between the two computers using Dropbox so, as you're implying, it must be something related to the environment on the computer or perhaps that one install of R is in some way different to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in RSQLite. It was reported here: https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/291

And fixed in 2.1.2: https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/releases/tag/v2.1.2